# WebView crash by null pointer at Bitmap.getWidth()

Tags: android, webview

I use WebView and got a crash as log below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
  at com.android.webview.chromium.Ap.getDefaultVideoPoster(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:565)
  at org.chromium.android_webview.DefaultVideoPosterRequestHandler$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source:2)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

On first line, it show Bitmap.getWidth() on null pointer but I did not use any Bitmap on my webview.

**Below is my code for webview**

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);     
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewResizer(), "WebViewResizer");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
        System.out.println("WEBVIEW LOAD PAGE FINISHED");
    }
});
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, URL, "text/html; charset=utf-8", null, "");
```

I tried to remove the line set chrome client but it did not help.

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

**URL is a script like this:**

```
 myScript = "<iframe width=\"500\" height=\"402\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/y7tEBhRp-MA\" frameborder=\"0\" gesture=\"media\" allow=\"encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

Does anyone get a same issue like me and how you resolve it?

Comment: The crash log you put doesn't help. Please post your logcat.

Comment: I am not sure if you can frame YouTube videos into the app

Comment: @statosdotcom the crash show only this log.

Comment: Ok. Following @matio suggestion, try opening another url, google.com for example. After that I would try to make it run without many of those `websettings` you've been using (motivated?) so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try my own implementation. Add below code to your CustomChromeClient;

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
    if (super.getDefaultVideoPoster() == null) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    } else {
        return super.getDefaultVideoPoster();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. But I have to find a way to pass into the CustomWebClient application context in order to get resources. Thanks

Comment: @leeCoder You can do that with custom Chome Client Constructor